# Сравнить два ключ обьекта JS с массивом

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Возник такой вопрос на повестке дня, сижу голову ломаю! Как можно сравнить ключ обьекта с массивом.
В общем у меня есть массив такого вида:

```
const stempTest = [
    { stemp: 'tr01', name: 'Тест' }, { stemp: 'tr02', name: "Тест" }, { stemp: 'tr03', name: "тест" }, { stemp: 'tr03', name: "тест" },
    { stemp: 'tr_04', name: "Тест" }
]
```

Мне нужно сравнивать приходящий с сервера обьект с stemp из массива и присваивать ему в "новом" обьекте значение name из массива. С сервера приходит обьект такого вида:

```
const obj = {

    tr01: { value: 3 },
    tr02: { value: 4 },
    tr03: { value: 5 },

}
```

Вот, в общем нужно сравнить obj.key и stempTest.stemp (stempTest это массив) и присвоить в новом обьекте значение name ключу obj.key

Пробовал через .filter прогонять в цикле с условием пока не заполнится новый обьект по длине такой же, как искомый с сервера, но почему-то не выходит!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  { stemp: 'tr01',    name: "Тест 1" },
  { stemp: 'tr02',    name: "Тест 2" },
  { stemp: 'tr03',    name: "тест 3" },
  { stemp: 'tr03',    name: "тест 4" },
  { stemp: 'tr_04',   name: "Тест 5" },
]

const obj = {
  tr01: { value: 3 },
  tr02: { value: 4 },
  tr03: { value: 5 },
}

for (const x of arr) {
  if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, x.stemp)) {
    obj[x.stemp].key = x.name
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)